# Скопировать содержимое переменной в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript

Скопировать содержимое переменной в буфер обмена
Задача состоит в том, что бы после загрузки js переменная отдавала в буфер обмена значения переменной.

```
<script>
var varName = 'Текст переменной';
</script>
```

Comment: Это команда или утверждение... А где вопрос?

Comment: Мы уже решили проблему в моем ответе, он прийдет и посмотрит:)

Comment: Мне казалось, что понятно. Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Через `clipboardData`:

```js
 const myData = "хахаха я подменил тебя";
 const modifyCopy = (e) => {
     e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain',  myData  );
     document.execCommand('copy');
     e.preventDefault();
 };

document.addEventListener('copy', modifyCopy);
```

```html
<input type="text">

<div>скопируй это!</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/onwoL9zm/) на JSFiddle.

Comment: Хм не срабатывает :(

Comment: Что пишет? Ошибку?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined
    at test.php:4

Comment: Я сейчас с телефона,  15 мин прийду все проверю и дам верный результат.

Comment: Буду благодарен!

Comment: Так это надо в js а не в php

Comment: Php не запускается <script>
const text = 'Текст переменной';
 window.clipboardData.setData("Text", text);
alert(123);
</script>

Comment: Хорошо прийду отпишусь:)

Comment: Договорились :)

Comment: Тестирую в хроме.

Comment: Дружище получилось!:) Я прикрепил рабочий пример в ответ:) C тебя `+` и ответ :D

Comment: К сожалению это не то что нужно. Задача состоит в том, что бы после загрузки js переменная отдавала в буфер обмена значения переменной.

Comment: Такого нет в JS но ты можешь записывать не на `copy`  как у меня,  а `paste`

Comment: то есть в js только после события может добавиться в буфер обмена?

Comment: К сожалению да. Так как мы вызываем `e.clipboardData` у события `copy` а у того же `load` к примеру такого нет.

Comment: Вообщем я старался помочь. Если что смотри в сторону `e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain',  myData  );`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Буду смотреть )