# Копирование текста с кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я делаю сайт для выбора криптокошелька, при выборе криптокошелька он появляется в кнопке при нажатии на которую текст с кнопки должен скопироваться. Как мне скопировать в буфер обмена текст с кнопки который меняется в зависимости от выбора пользователя.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества ничего подобного, всё понятно.

Comment: [Clipboard.writeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скопировать содержимое переменной в буфер обмена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825109/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

текст у кнопки берется как element.innerText (если это именно кнопка и текст, а не какой-то другой элемент; сути это, впрочем, не меняет)

копирование - Clipboard API

(в сниппете не сработает, т.к. политика безопасности запрещает это во фреймах и неактивных вкладках)

```js
function copyText(someText) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(someText);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyText(this.innerText)">This is some text</button>
```

Comment: Если в вашем коде нельзя воспроизвести решения, но не вставляйте его как воспроизводимый код.

Comment: @ΝNL993, а решение прекрасно воспроизводимо, только ограничения браузера не дают его запустить в сниппете. А что, использовать сниппет как источник форматированного содержимого запрещено?